# Signalr.js not found

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I've just followed the "Get started with SignalR on ASP.NET Core" article and I get an error when I open the browser.
The error is: GET https://localhost:5001/lib/signalr/signalr.js 404 (Not Found)

Article link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/get-started?tabs=visual-studio-code&view=aspnetcore-2.1

The same error happens when I try to run their own example: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/signalr/get-started/sample

.NET Core SDK: dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-preview1-008174-win-x64

NPM version: 5.8.0

VSCode: 1.22.2

Any help, please!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [instructions for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/get-started?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.1#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q-1_visual-studio):

> 4. Copy the *signalr.js* file from *node_modules\@aspnet\signalr\dist\browser* to the *lib* folder in your project.

Comment: If you choose the "Visual Studio Code" option the instruction is not present. If you choose "Visual Studio" the instructions appear. Thanks a lot!